# Use a PHP variable within an SQL statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, wordpress

I am using wordpress and I have an SQL statement (as below) to gather the tags for a specific category. The only issue with this is that the table names may change (i.e. they will not always be wp_*). The function `$pfx = $wpdb->base_prefix;` returns what the wordpress database prefix is.

How can I use `$pfx` inside my SQL statement below (instead of wp_ ).

```
global $wpdb;
$tags = $wpdb->get_results
("
SELECT DISTINCT terms2.term_id as tag_id, terms2.name as tag_name, null as tag_link, t2.count as post_total
    FROM
        wp_posts as p1
        LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships as r1 ON p1.ID = r1.object_ID
        LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy as t1 ON r1.term_taxonomy_id = t1.term_taxonomy_id
        LEFT JOIN wp_terms as terms1 ON t1.term_id = terms1.term_id,

        wp_posts as p2
        LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships as r2 ON p2.ID = r2.object_ID
        LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy as t2 ON r2.term_taxonomy_id = t2.term_taxonomy_id
        LEFT JOIN wp_terms as terms2 ON t2.term_id = terms2.term_id

    WHERE
        t1.taxonomy = 'category' AND p1.post_status = 'publish' AND terms1.term_id IN (".$args['categories'].") AND
        t2.taxonomy = 'post_tag' AND p2.post_status = 'publish'
        AND p1.ID = p2.ID
    ORDER BY post_total DESC
");
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change for example

```
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships
```

into

```
LEFT JOIN ".$pfx."term_relationships
```

Comment: Sorry, I got the quotes wrong, since you are using double quotes. Corrected.

Comment: Thanks, but I'd already tried with double quotes, and again it still doesn't work. I'm not really sure what's going on..

Comment: Have you made sure that $pfx actually contains a value, and that the table specified actually exists? Also, do you receive any errors when you do it? Just saying that it "doesn't work" doesn't help us help you.

Comment: Yes I can verify that variable `$pfx` does contain the correct database prefix. However, the query is actually a function to which a category ID is passed and (if it all works), said category's tags are returned. However after changing the `wp_` with `".$pfx."` the function does not return any tags when used.

Comment: You did set `$pfx` *inside the function* and dumped its content there, too, didn't you?

Comment: That's cracked it, thanks! I had set `$pfx` on the line before the function started, and now its inside of the function it works. Cheers

Comment: Just a tip... For long queries like that I prefer to use the [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) string syntax, which allows you to avoid the whole single-quote double-quote confusion...